# Grails 3.1.8 application not running

Tags: grails, build.gradle

My Grails 3.1.8 application not running,
Following log found when i want to run application-

```
|Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...
|Running application...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
debug option to get more log output.
Error |
Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Comment: Can you run app with --stacktrace option to get full trace